# How can I test a mobile version of our website?

Tags: asp.net, mobile, web

I have no up to date mobile phone personally, and we don't have any in our team to allow us to test mobile versions of our ASP.Net websites.

We have now been asked to provide a mobile version of our website (which is a fairly busy site) but I have no means to check the mobile pages.

Any suggestions? Are there emulators or would it better to have the real thing?

Comment: Trying various results on Google showed some promising pages, please state what you have tried already and if so how they were not suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to have the real thing, but if that's not an option, I have used a plugin for FireFox called ["User Agent Switcher"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/)

Another route you could go is to get the Android SDK and load up an emulator. It runs a full version of android, so you could open the browser from there (You could also change screen size/device type) - a little more heavy than the first solution, but potentially another route worth exploring.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `simulators/emulators` - Android, iPhone etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well Apple provide an iOS emulator, which you can download in the developers section of Apple's own website.

Outside of that, the only other testing environment I'm aware of is Ripple, which is a plugin for Chrome, designed to emulate a range of mobile devices. You can find that at: http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/.

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered there is a lot of different tools to do the testing and that is all fine to a certain extent, for daily testing by developers and testers.

But with 15 years of testing behind me I would never let the site go untested with a few different real devices if the site is an important service - usually this can be done with "staff" phones at no cost if the cost is the problem. I would more or less say; can your company live with publishing a site out there and there might be a risk it won't work on some mobile platforms?

Answer (score 0):

[DeviceAnywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com) is the tool that we have used a lot. It provides you access to numerous mobile devices using which you can test both apps and websites. They have placed several physical devices which you can see and operate remotely.

It is always better to test on real devices instead of emulators. During development phase, emulators are helpful but for final delivery it is best to test on real phones. Mobile web browsers may or may not support HTML,CSS,JS completely and their individual implementation could be different.